# Identity column in oracle changes to none

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g, sequence-sql

I've been dealing with this problem for some time now.
I have a table with a column that acts as ID, I need a sequence of numbers to identify each one. So I'm using the Identity column feature in Oracle 11g, and it works fine, but after a little while, when I insert a new row I get the "ora-01400 cannot insert null into..." error, so I go and check if my identity column is still "configured" that way, and it's not.
I don't know, am I maybe skipping a step?

The code for the sequence that gets created is:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE  "ELABOR"."WF_CONF_SEQ4"  MINVALUE 1 MAXVALUE 9999999999999999999999999999 INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 981 CACHE 20 NOORDER  NOCYCLE ;
```

And this is the code for the trigger:

```
create or replace TRIGGER WF_CONF_TRG4 
    BEFORE INSERT ON WF_CONF 
    FOR EACH ROW 
    BEGIN
      <<COLUMN_SEQUENCES>>
      BEGIN
        IF INSERTING AND :NEW.ID IS NULL THEN
           SELECT WF_CONF_SEQ5.NEXTVAL INTO :NEW.ID FROM SYS.DUAL;
        END IF;
      END COLUMN_SEQUENCES;
END;
```

Does anyone know what could be wrong?
I appreciate your help!
Have a great day.

Comment: Please show relevant code.

Comment: Show us the script for the sequence and its usage

Comment: When you say "check if my identity column is still "configured" that way" do you mean you check if the trigger exists? If so, does the trigger still exist but it's disabled, or does the trigger not exist at all? If the latter, was the table dropped and recreated at any point? Triggers get dropped when the table does, so they need to be explicitly recreated when the table is re-added.

Comment: Hi @Boneist both the trigger and the sequence still exist and in status the trigger has VALID assigned, it's just the table that in type has "none" as it is when you create a table with non incremental values. And nop, the table was never dropped.
Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure that it's NULL that's being written into your ID column, and not some other column that is NULL?